# Can't find a #include

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm using the Marlin 2.0.3 for a 3D printer project. I'd like to tear apart the code, but I don't see a #include to anything in the Marlin.ino, Configuration.h, Configuration_adv.h, nor Version.h.

If I use a verbose compilation, I see the ./src/HAL/HAL_AVR/HAL.cpp is the first thing it tries to include, but I don't see that writen in the code.

How does it know what to include?

Incase you can answer without downloading it:
Marlin.ino and Version.h is just comments.
Configuration.h and Configuration_adv.h are just a bunch of #defines.

Link to Marlin: https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/releases/tag/2.0.3

Comment: The IDE compiles everything in the src/ folder too...

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense. Thanks!